# Show that any group of order 20 is not simple?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Show that any group of order $20$ is not simple.

Denote the group $G$. It seems intuitive to state first that $20=2^2 \times 5$. Sylow's theorem then states that since a prime number, $5$, divides the order of $G$, we must have a subgroup of $G$ of order $5$. Where do I go from here?

Comment: The standard thing to do from here is to use Sylow 3 to figure out whether one of the Sylow subgroups has to be normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Sylow, the number $n_5$ of Sylow $5$-subgroups of $G$ divides $4$ and satisfies $$n_5 \equiv 1 \mod 5.$$
Therefore we must have $n_5 = 1$, but this is equivalent to saying that the Sylow $5$-subgroup is normal.